# Using ReactJS and python Flask. General Approach

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I am working on project, that I started with Python and Flask, as at the begginning it was quite small - the jinja templates commonly used by Flask was sufficient, but as I wanted more and more - I decided to give a try to ReactJS.

It works great for variety of things, and there is bigger control of whole frontend, and generally I like it, but Let's assume that I want to use react for X component, and in the same X component i'd like to use jinja templates - to populate it with data from Flask backend. This is the first question - 1) How should be this achieved? React is preparing javascript file, so the tempalte can't be rendered. Should I create some endpoint, and GET data needed to populate with jquery request?

The second question is - the routing. I define some endpoints in flask - but in react components I need to 'hardcode' it. Is there some solution to not have it hardcoded in 2 places?

The third question is - how do you work with that? Maybe good point is to combine React for some components, and use tempaltes for other things?

**Summarizing question:**

1. How to inject flask data into React components.
2. How to face routing.
3. General points of working with React + Flask / Django. Your opinion/thoughts/guides.

I am very interested in your opinions about this two frameworks working together :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can make two separate apps, one with flask (endpoints serving json data) and one with react (a frontend app, that requests this data). You can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) in react to make requests to your api. For example you write a class/component for that purpose and use that to request data in a few lines of code in Your other components. If jinja  You mentioned is a templating engine I don't think there is an easy way to use that with react.
2. In React You usually develop Single Page Applications, but You can use [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) in order to route your subpages. If I understand correctly this is a situation You are talking about: In react You write a component that is responsible for displaying a list of articles. In that component You 'hardcode' a function using (using axios for example) that download the list in json format. Later You do the same for a component that displays a specific article.
3. I think it's easier to be consistent and develop a SPA application. Especially when You have things like react-router, axios or redux already set up. I'm a beginner ( don't be harsh on me (: ), but I think these frameworks should work with each other just fine. I recommend [this udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/). I learned there a lot about react.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Adrian - I am also begginer level - and I am trying to get more overwiev on that. I think that having the clear view on how these two should work, is >50% of success - the rest is the implementation :P
Your comment is making my mind up, but i want more views on this :D

Comment: That makes sense, glad I could help (: